# Did I do the right thing in rolling back this edit?

Tags: discussion, edits, flags, suggested-edits

So I was going through some of the unanswered questions over the last few days in the [tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tkinter) tag and came across this question:

[Refresh for an array of labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48834727/refresh-for-an-array-of-labels)

When I went to read the code I saw that the question made reference to a function that wasn't present in the example, so naturally, the first thing I did was check the edit history and found that [revision 2](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/18846672) removed a huge chunk of code from the question and completely invalidated the example given, making it impossible to run, the changes don't seem specifically malicious at all though. Even more concerning is that the edit was approved by two other users.

I rolled the question back to its original state, added the relevant formatting changes from revision 2 (some of the changes were not needed) and flagged for moderator attention in case the user is doing similar things elsewhere.

Is this the right thing to do in these circumstances?

Comment: Sound about right. Not sure what you said in the mod flag but if it is a request to investigate edit behavior I assume everything will be OK.

Comment: Look at some of their recent edits, this doesn't appear to be a habit with them though I have seen more suggested edits recently that delete more than they should have.

Comment: #1 here before you start to fiddle with edits is to ask yourself: can this question even be answered without further clarification by none else but the OP? If the answer to that is no, then the question should be closed. If the OP provides sufficient clarification, it should be open and _then_ at that point, we can consider if the post would benefit from edits. Otherwise you are just wasting time polishing crap.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't think a whole-hog rollback would've been *appropriate*, given that in spite of the edit removing code, it improved much of the actual question.  A surgical edit simply re-adding the removed code **with a detailed edit message explaining where the code suddenly came from** would've probably been enough to accomplish your immediate goal.

I also don't see much value in the moderator flag.  One occurrence is dealt with here by yourself.  If you personally observed *multiple* instances of the editor wantonly and abusively removing code from questions, *then* it'd make sense to get a moderator involved.

Comment: I agree, although it would have been better if the original editor left a detailed edit message explaining why the code suddenly went away instead of just "improved formatting". (Not that the person asking this question could do anything about that.)

Comment: I added back in the majority of the edits that had been added in revision 2, some of them were a little overzealous. I'll take the advice about the mod flag on board, wasn't sure whether it was worthwhile alerting mods or not.

Comment: One potential reason to flag for moderator (and I'm just saying _potential_, not really advocating either way at this point) is so that they can decide whether the two robots who accepted the initial edit need a bit of schooling. It's happened in the past on occasion.